# Using Swift to sort array of NSString's results in low memory warning

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, nsstring, malloc

I'm implementing a search function in which the end result is an `Array` of `NSString`, sorted by how closely they resemble the search string.  The fuzzy match algorithm is custom, and typically doesn't have a problem.

It does, however, have a memory issue when the `Array` contains thousands of `NSString` that are very similar (i.e. Title, Copy of Title, Title 2).  Instruments reports that the persistent memory at the time of crash is 98% from `malloc` of `NSString` with my fuzzy match algorithm being the responsible caller.

On smaller sets (2,000 random strings) that don't crash, the memory is released and everything appears behave expectedly.  Any thoughts on how to decrease the large memory usage?

```
data = data.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
    var itemString = self.converter(item)
    return itemString.scoreAgainst(string) > 0
}).sorted({ (item1, item2) -> Bool in
    var string1 = self.converter(item1)
    var string2 = self.converter(item2)
    return string1.scoreAgainst(string) > string2.scoreAgainst(string)
})
```

The method `scoreAgainst` is really kosher.  It just does a series of lowercasing, uppercasing, `rangeOfString:` and `substringWithRange:` to give a score for the match.

Comment: An autoreleasepool may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If memory is getting released when its done, but the peak memory usage is too high, you would employ `autoreleasepool` to minimize peak memory usage:

```
data = data.filter { (item) -> Bool in
    var isPositive: Bool!
    autoreleasepool {
        let itemString = self.converter(item)
        isPositive = itemString.scoreAgainst(string) > 0
    }
    return isPositive
}.sorted { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
    var isGreaterThan: Bool!
    autoreleasepool {
        let string1 = self.converter(item1)
        let string2 = self.converter(item2)
        isGreaterThan = string1.scoreAgainst(string) > string2.scoreAgainst(string)
    }
    return isGreaterThan
}
```

---

As Alex points out, if `converter` and `scoreAgainst` are expensive, you might want to reduce the number of calls you have to do by calling this only once for each item (though I would suggest you still need `autoreleasepool`, because this simpler logic reduces the number of calls to your routine, but doesn't eliminate it):

```
data = data.map {
        item -> (String, Double) in
        var score: Double!
        autoreleasepool {
            score = self.converter(item).scoreAgainst(string)
        }
        return (item, score)
    }
    .filter { $0.1 > 0 }
    .sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
    .map { $0.0 }
```

It wasn't clear if `item1` was a `String` or whatever, so you'd want to make sure the `in` statement of the `map` call matches it, but hopefully it illustrates the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution!  Here's a gist with the final code that got it working.  Feel free to update your answer to include this.
https://gist.github.com/jslinker/782208045b4cbe98ad60

Answer (score 2):

You are doing something very expensive and repetitive there; constructing two new objects in each call to compare.

In principle, compare might be called as many as N^2 times (for a very bad sort algorithm), and more likely N.log(N) times.

how about the following code:

```
data = Array(zip2(data,data.map(self.converter($0).scoreAgainst(string)>0)))
  .filter({ (item,score) -> Bool in
    return score > 0
}).sorted({ (item1, item2) -> Bool in
    return item1.score > item2.score
}).map({(item,score) in item})
```

Here we calculate the score N times, instead of N + N.log(N) times, and avoid constructing the temporary objects.

Comment: Nice optimization on eliminating extraneous calls to `converter` and `scoreAgainst`. I might suggest http://pastie.org/10048207 as further simplification. Thing is, though, this defers the `autoreleasepool` problem, but doesn't solve it. I suspect that you'll still need to add the pool. But good catch on the inefficiency problem here!

Comment: The auto release problem will become a lot less pressing when the extra object construction is reduced from between 4,000 and 4,000,000 extra objects created.